# Using a single computer to show two websites in kiosk mode

Tags: linux, xorg

I've written two web pages that show the status of a internal application. The idea was to display both of them, on two different monitors, using only a single PC with two graphic cards.

The system will be mounted to a wall and has no keyboard or mouse. That's why I need a script that will automatically launch two instances of firefox (in kiosk mode), each on it's own monitor.

Currently the OS installed on the PC is OpenSuse, but I'm free to install a different linux flavor.

So, how do I launch firefox on a specific monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox follows the `--display=` X11 convention. You'll need to find the `$DISPLAY` value of your second monitor, but probably it's just `:0.1`